# What does sizeof (function(argument)) return?

Tags: c, sizeof

What will be the output of program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(char *a){
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(a));
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    char a[20];
    printf("%d\n",sizeof (fun(a)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: its not really `sizeof(function)`, but rather `sizeof(function())` or `sizeof(int)`

Comment: StackOverflow has great searching capabilities. Please use them before asking a question. For example this search string: `[sizeof] function` would give you many related questions including this one: [Output of using sizeof on a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988227/output-of-using-sizeof-on-a-function)

Comment: @jarekczek, that particular question isn't a dupe (though other may be) - it specifically asks about the size of the function rather than the size of the return value from a function.

Comment: You know, I wonder whether people even _bother_ to check proposed dupes before closing. One is for a function designator itself, _not_ a function "call". Hence it's not the same thing. The other is for the size of an array! Voting to reopen.

Comment: jarekczek: both of the links posted above question aren't similar to the question asked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Except with variable length arrays, `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand. So it will just yield the size of `fun(a)` type, *i.e.* `sizeof(int)` (without calling the function).

> **C11 (n1570) §6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**
>
> 2 [...] If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
> integer constant.

Answer (score 4):

It returns the size of the return type from that function (`4` on my implementation since that's what an `int` takes up for me), which you would discover had you run it as is, then changed the return type to `char` (at which point it would give you `1`).

The relevant part of the C99 standard is `6.5.3.4.The sizeof operator`:

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; **otherwise, the operand is not evaluated** and the result is an integer constant.

Keep in mind that bold bit, it means that the function itself is *not* called (hence the `printf` within it is not executed). In other words, the output is simply the size of your `int` type (followed by a newline, of course).

Answer (score 3):

The function returns `int`, so it's `sizeof(int)`, which, on 32 bit systems is typically 4 bytes. Though it could be 2 or 8, depending on implementation.

Comment: the size of int is platform dependent

Comment: Not necessarily 4 bytes... On many embedded systems an int is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

keyword sizeof followed by ellipsis returns the number of elements in a parameter pack.

The type of the result is the unsigned integral type size_t defined in the header file