# Warning:argument to 'sizeof' [-Werror=sizeof-pointer-memaccess]

Tags: c, warnings

I am  getting  the below warning while compiling with gcc4.8.5  :

```
Boolean_t bsnap_isFileExtensionValid (const char *suffix)
{
    .......
    .......
    ......... 

    strncpy (gbsnapSuffix, suffix,/*sizeof MAXPATHLEN*/(suffix ));

}


 warning: argument to 'sizeof' in 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)' call is the same expression as the source; did you mean to provide an explicit length? [-Werror=sizeof-pointer-memaccess]
         strncpy (gbsnapSuffix, suffix,sizeof(suffix ));
```

How to solve this type of warning?
Do i need to  disable the compilation option?

Comment: `suffix` is a pointer,, so `sizeof(suffix)` is going to be probably 4 or 8 depending on your machine architecture. You most likely want the length of the string pointed to by `suffix`, or the size of the memory chunk it's pointing to (which you'll have to separately keep track of). Also, be careful with `strncpy`, it's not guaranteed to NUL terminate your destination string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does sizeof (function(argument)) return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659486/what-does-sizeof-functionargument-return)

Comment: Then i changed to strlen(suffix).

Comment: @himsikha do you know what strncpy actually does? because that is not a very useful thing to do

Comment: @immibis strncpy will copy some bytes from source to destination.

Comment: If you use `strlen(suffix)` the result will be the same as using `strcpy`, which I'm sure you are not using because someone said it is unsafe. The size is supposed to be the size of the target, to guard against overflowing it.

Comment: its solved now,i changed to  sizeof(dest) instead of sizeof(src).

Comment: If `dest` is the destination *array* and not a pointer, it should work.

Comment: yeah,its working now.